# SQL join on another column with fewer conditions if first condition fails

Tags: sql, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table, table 1 with the following columns:

[image]

I also have a table (table2) with the following columns

[image]

I want to left join table 1 with table2 with the following logic:

```
i) try to match on 
table2.zipcode = (table1.loc_zip_cd if table1.loc_zip_cd is not null 
                 or table1.set_cip_cd if table1.loc_zip_cd is null)
and
table1.year = table2.year and
table1.category = table2.category
```

if the join returns null on the right hand side with conditions above,

```
ii) try to match on
table1.year = table2.st_year
table1.category = table2.category
```

..
..

**How would I accomplish this? Here is my attempt using a coalesce but it did not work.**
..
..

```
get_results = spark.sql(""" select table1.*,table2.zipcode, table2.factor_ppqqrr from table1

                left join table2 on
                
                COALESCE(table1.year= table2.year and
                table1.category=table2.category and
                table2.zipcode =
                CASE
                    WHEN table1.loc_zip_cd IS NOT NULL THEN SUBSTRING(table1.loc_zip_cd,1,3)
                    WHEN table1.set_zip_cd IS NOT NULL THEN SUBSTRING(table1.set_zip_cd,1,3)
                END, 
                table1.year= table2.st_year and
                table1.category=table2.category)
                
                """)
```

Comment: I am not familiar with spark.sql but knowing sql , instead of COALESCE can't you use "OR" instead ?

Comment: with or, would it look at the first condition and go into the second if the first returned a null?

Comment: is it intended that st_year is different from year (i.e. that a different year column is used in each predicate)?

Comment: It's typical "or" as in all languages. Either condition matches will give you the result. Isn't if the first condition is false equally treated as null ? Or do you mean one row in table1 should not satisfy both conditions? Would be nice if you put some expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join it twice and then pick your preferential columns:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(t2a.year, t2b.year),
  COALESCE(t2a.column_you_prefer, t2b.column_youll_accept),
FROM
  table1
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2a
  ON  
    t2a.zipcode = COALESCE(table1.loc_zip_cd, table1.set_cip_cd) AND
    t2a.year = table1.year AND
    t2a.category = table1.category

  LEFT JOIN table2 t2b
  ON
    t2b.year = table1.year AND
    t2b.category = table1.category
```